# What's the best workflow when you have one git server and several development stations?

Tags: git, project-management

I have a git server where my project reside, I have a laptop that I often work on, a work computer that I use a lot and a desktop at home. The general GIT workflow I have no problem with (branching, merging, tagging etc.), but how do I make sure that I don't have any changes laying on one of the computers when I start working on another one? All the computers has my project cloned, but rarely do I have a change worth commiting when I have to leave the computer. To deal with this I have a tendency to just push a commit I call "Save" with all my small unrelated file changes every time I'm done working. Then I do a pull when I start working on another computer.

This seems like a hacky solution though and I have a feeling certain people would punch me in the face if they saw how I was using GIT. I just can't see any alternatives to this short of carrying only one checkout of my project around on a thumb drive.

So I ask you professionals: **How do you deal with working with multiple clones of a project on different computers?**

---

*Examples*

- A thumb drive with only one clone of the project?
- Somehow making temporary commits that you pull and delete later?
- Some clever "save" branch that is used for this purpose only?
- Does GIT perhaps have support for this issue built-in? Online stashing?
- etc...

Comment: This might help you - [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't think it would happen, but I found a perfect solution: **[Dropbox](http://dropbox.com/)**!

I simply keep my "working copy" repository in the Dropbox folder at all times. The working copy will sync between all my development PCs. I can't think of a reason why this isn't an absolutely perfect solution, looking away from the obvious but negligible drawback that I require an internet connection at all times.

I'm guessing the new [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com) will do the same job.

Answer (score 3):

One of my coworkers uses a sort of "personal" branch for developing like this. Even though it's a remote branch on our primary Git server, no one else is pushing or pulling it, so he's not worried about incomplete or bad commits.

That may be the most Git-like solution, but you still have to remember to commit and push before you leave for the day, or else you'll still have changes sitting on one machine. Keeping the repo on the thumb drive would mitigate that problem. Then you just have to worry about keeping up with physical media.

I wouldn't suggest purposefully committing incomplete code with the intent of reverting it later, especially if other developers are working on the project. That just sounds dirty :-)

Comment: What do you think of the DropBox solution?

Comment: If multiple developers are sharing a single repo via Dropbox, they run the risk of pushing during a sync and potentially corrupting the repo. But I imagine that works very well for a single developer on multiple machines, as long as you're diligent about pulling and verifying each time you switch boxes.

Comment: When do anyone ever share the same local repo? I can't imagine a scenario where that would happen :P

Comment: I've done this before. You still set up a remote (bare) repository in your Dropbox folder and share that with the other developers. Then everybody pulls from and pushes to the Dropbox folder on their machines, and Dropbox is responsible for syncing. You aren't sharing a local repo. It's a quick-and-dirty hack and I wouldn't recommend it for long-term development, but it'll do in a pinch.

Comment: Well it's not even a problem for me, since I don't plan on sharing my local repo with anybody. I'm simply using Dropbox to sync the local repo between my own computers, and for that Dropbox is a perfect solution indeed

Answer (score 0):

I'm in this situation too. Being on Windows with all PCs on the same LAN, I've shared repositories of all PCs I'm developing on, and added each one as remote of the others. When I switch from PC A to PC B, I commit on PC A, and `git pull A` on PC B.

I only keep the server as the "trusted" repository, and only push releases on it. So it's quite the same workflow as yours, and I don't find it hacky.

Been using this since months of regular use, and no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I push these "temp branches" to the central repo. If you don't want anyone to see your half-finished work, you can set up an unfuddle account or use a USB stick and push those there.